# ListView is working in some devices and blank in some devices

Tags: android, listview

What I am facing is that I have a database which is prepopulated and working well. I'm using a `ListView` to show some of my database's contents.
Well, the problem is `ListView` is working without any error (even in logcat) in many devices and emulators and is blank in my Honor 6x (Nougat). 
It's just blank and there's no error in logcat except `E/HW-JPEG-DEC: [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null` which I think is not related to my problem.
This is MyDatabase.java

```
 public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "plethora.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public Cursor getNames() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        int i =3;
        String [] sqlSelect = {"1 _id", "Name"};
        String sqlTables = "Names";
        String selection = "_id = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { ""+i };
        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, selection, selectionArgs,
                null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }
 }
```

This is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Cursor Names;
    private MyDatabase db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus_route);
        db = new MyDatabase(this);
        Names = db.getNames();
        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                Names,
                new String[] {"Name"},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="Studios.Example.com.Database.Names"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/lv1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/listV1"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried to set a background to `ListView` to check whether it's displayed or not and I can see the background on the screen in my phone but In others, I can see the whole list data.
I've tried some suggestions provided on this website but nothing worked.
Any help/advice/solution will be appreciated. Thanks.